# JSON problem solution

Tags: jquery, json

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LqyLb/2/) fiddle. I want to alert the background. How can I?

Thanks.

Comment: Where does the json come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You must eval the JSON string to get an object.
2. The background value is missing quotes.

It works like this:

```
var gib = eval("({background:'default.jpg'})");
alert(gib.background)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax in json.

```
var gib={background:"default.jpg"};
alert(gib.background);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently just instantiating a string, rather than a JSON object - JSON objects are not surrounded in quotes.

Here's the fixed version:

```
var gib = { background : "default.jpg "};
alert(gib.background)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the json to be valid like this 
var gib={"background":"default.jpg"}

So yes parse into object first 
if using jquery jQuery.parseJSON( "{background:default.jpg}" );
alert(gib.background)